# Android Studio Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, git, gradle, default

I'm trying to import and compile this android opensource application found on GitHub. When I build, gradle sync fails and this error is shown:
Error: Configuration with name' default' not found.

I looked for a solution online and understood that it should have to do with libraries used in the project. The problem I can't understand which one and how to solve.
In many cases, changes were made to [settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLpjE.png).
Could anyone help me?
Project repo: https://github.com/erincandescent/Impeller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Project repo: https://github.com/erincandescent/Impeller

You **can't build** this project **without doing same changes**.

In the `settings.gradle` there are:

```
include ':impellerapi'
include ':jiraconnect-android-main'
include ':tokenautocomplete:library'The settings.gradle
```

and it **is not clear what is** `include ':impellerapi'`.

Also in the root folder there are files like `AndroidManifest.xml` or `res` folder **that shouldn't be there**.

Also the `build.gradle` in the root folder **is not a top-level file**, it is just a module build.gradle.
It looks like a module was pushed in the root folder instead of a module folder.

Also the project is very old, and **you have to update all the components** inside the `build.gradle` for example:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
    }
```